# image uploads using carrierwave backgrounder, then listening for finished uploads so I can reload the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

I am using jquery-fileupload-rails/carrierwave/carrierwave_background/sidekiq/fog+s3 to do this:

Allow user to upload an image, process this image (create multiple versions/sizes) in the background with sidekiq, then upload these versions + original to Amazon S3. This works fine. (Though I suspect this is probably a really inefficient/crappy way to do this, and I should be uploading directly using client-side javascript. But I don't know how to do that.) The user goes to a new photo page to upload a photo, and then gets redirected to the photo index page which shows all the photos. The problem is that since it takes a while to process the images, when the user is redirected to the index, the processing hasn't happened yet. Instead the user sees a 'processing image...' text where the image would be, based on a flag that is set on the image record. (I picked most of this up from a ryan bates railscast.) This is, obviously, not a great way to ingratiate to your users!

Is there any way to have the index page listen for the flag to be (un)set, or for something else to happen so that it will reload itself when it's ready to display the photo?
My new photo form looks something like this:

```
    = simple_form_for @photo, url: user_photos_path(@user) do |f|
      %span.fileupload-new
        Choose a file
      = f.file_field :image, label: "Choose a file:", id: 'upload-field'
      = f.button :submit, 'Upload photo'
```

the photos#index looks something like this:

```
      %ol
        - photos.each do |photo|
          %li
            %figure
              - if photo.image_processing?
                %em processing photo...
              - else
                = image_tag(photo.image_url(:standard))
```

Any advice would be appreciated, whether it is a solution or just a different way of approaching this. Thanks.

Comment: In case people point me there, I have read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437075/how-to-reload-page-after-uploading-images?rq=1) but I can't figure where his image_upload redirects to after he's done, or is it the redirect that is delayed? I don't wish to do that, obviously, because there'd be: a) no point in backgrounding anything; b) not everything in the index is going to be "processing" since previously uploaded and processed photos should display just fine.